# How to enable public query appsync amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, gatsby, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Amplify with Appsync. I want to add a public query `listproducts` and it is giving me the hardest time. Based on my understanding, I know that public access needs to be given using `apiKey` or `iam`. The trouble is that my mutation `enroll` lambda function internally makes a `create` mutation and it is using `iam` permissions to create those records. I have enabled `allowUnauthenticatedIdentities=true` but I keep getting access denied for the `listproducts` query when using iam permissions. I need to make sure that if I go with the iam method, that I have a way to distinguish between the public iam and the private iam that is doing the administrative work in my `enroll` call and I don't see a way to dictate whether I'd want to use an authenticated vs unauthenticated iam role.

```
type Product @aws_iam {
  id: ID!

}

type UserCourse
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
      { allow: owner, operations: [read] }
      { allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [create, read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  courseId: String
  invoice: String
}

type Query {
  listproducts: [Product]
    @function(name: "listproducts-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }])
}

type Mutation {
  enroll(courseId: String, priceId: String, source: String): UserCourse
    @function(name: "coursesenroll-${env}")
}
```

What am I missing here? I am connecting using Gatsby and `AWSAppSyncClient`. Is there some trivial way of doing this that I'm just missing? My ideal world would be that I could run an unauthenticated query with cognito pools and it would return so I didn't have to deal with instantiating different appsyncclient's based on whether I'm logged in or not. I tried manually adding permissions to the unauth role and I'm not sure if that's the right approach but I'd be happy to go this route too if I can't do unauth out of the box with amplify.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:eu-central-1:SOME_LONG_STRING:apis/SOME_LONG_STRING/types/Query/fields/listproducts"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```